# Multiplication on nested fields on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, multiplication

In a database in MongoDB I am trying to group some data by their date (one group for each day of the year), and then add an additional field that would be the result of the multiplication of two of the already existing fields.

The data structure is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("567a7c6d9da4bc18967a3947"), 
    "units" : 3.0, 
    "price" : 50.0, 
    "name" : "Name goes here", 
    "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-23T10:50:21.560+0000")
}
```

I first tried a two stage approach using `$project` and then `$group` like this

```
db.things.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: { 
          "_id" : 1, 
          "name" : 1, 
          "units" : 1, 
          "price" : 1, 
          "datetime":1,
          "unitsprice" : { $multiply: [ "$price", "$units" ] }
          }

    },

    {
      $group: { 
          "_id" : {
              "day" : {
                  "$dayOfMonth" : "$datetime"
              }, 
              "month" : {
                  "$month" : "$datetime"
              }, 
              "year" : {
                  "$year" : "$datetime"
              }
          }, 
          "things" : {
              "$push" : "$$ROOT"
          }
      }
    }
  ],
)
```

in this case, the first step (the `$project`) gives the expected output (with the expected value of unitsprice), but then when doing the second `$group` step, it outputs this error:

> "errmsg":$multiply only supports numeric types, not String",
>   "code":16555

I tried also turning around things, doing the `$group` step first and then the `$project`

```
db.things.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group: { 
          "_id" : {
              "day" : {
                  "$dayOfMonth" : "$datetime"
              }, 
              "month" : {
                  "$month" : "$datetime"
              }, 
              "year" : {
                  "$year" : "$datetime"
              }
          }, 
          "things" : {
              "$push" : "$$ROOT"
          }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: { 
          "_id" : 1, 
          "things":{
              "name" : 1, 
              "units" : 1, 
              "price" : 1, 
              "datetime":1,
              "unitsprice" : { $multiply: [ "$price", "$units" ] }
          }
      }

    }
  ],
);
```

But in this case, the result of the multiplication is: `unitsprice:null`

Is there any way of doing this multiplication? Also, it would be nice to do it in a way that the output would not have nested fields, so it would look like:

```
{"_id":
 "units":
 "price":
 "name":
 "datetime":
 "unitsprice":
}
```

Thanks in advance

PS:I am running MongoDB 3.2

Comment: The query worked for me. Is it possible that somewhere in the collection you have price or unit fields with bad type?

You can check it with such query:

    db.things.find({$or: [{price: {$not: {$type:1}}}, {units: {$not: {$type:1}}} ]}

Comment: Yep, I have both Double and Int32 fields. Should I change everything to double? Any clue about how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Double and Int32 should work just fine. I don't think you need to change everything to double.

Comment: I've checked and all units and price fields are either Int32 or Double, so the problem doesn't seem to be there, but thanks anyway. Also take in account that by doing the first approach (first $project, then $group), the multiplication did give the expected output, it is only then after the $group step that I got the error message

Comment: Is this your real data structure?

Comment: Yep, the data structure is exactly as I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the error. When importing one of the fields, a few of the `price` fields were created as a `string`. Surprisingly, the error didn't came out when first doing the `multiplication` in the `project` step (the output was normal until it reached the first wrong field, then it stopped), but when doing the `group` step.
In order to find the text fields I used this query:

> db.things.find( { price: { $type: 2 } } );

Thanks for the hints